# How can I open original activities by clicking a listview item after filtering listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, intentfilter

My code is working fine when it comes to clicking items. But the problem arises when I try to open activities after filtering listview. It always opens activity 1.

Here is my source code.

navigate.java

```
    public class navigate extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    EditText editsearch;
    String[] rank;
    String[] names;

    int[] flag;
    ArrayList<Object> arraylist = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        // Generate sample data
        rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6","7","8","9","10","11"};

        names = new String[] { "Animal Bite", "Asthma Attack", "Choking","CPR","Black eye",
                "Drowning", "Fracture","Heart Attack","Insect Bite","Poisoning","Spinal Injury",};


        flag = new int[] { R.drawable.animal,
                R.drawable.asthma, R.drawable.choke, R.drawable.cpricon,
                R.drawable.blckeye,R.drawable.drown,R.drawable.fracture,R.drawable.hrtattck,R.drawable.insect,R.drawable.poison,R.drawable.spinal };

        // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++) 
        {
            Object wp = new Object(rank[i], names[i], flag[i]);
            // Binds all strings into an array
            arraylist.add(wp);
        }

        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
        editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

        // Capture Text in EditText
        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    final int position, long id) {
                switch ((int) adapter.getItemId(position)) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent newActivity = new    Intent(navigate.this, animalbite.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;
                    case 1:Intent newActivity1 = new    Intent(navigate.this, asthmaattack.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity1);
                        break;
                    case 2:Intent newActivity2 = new    Intent(navigate.this, animalbite.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity2);
                        break;}

            }
        });
    }


}
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Object> objectList = null;
    private ArrayList<Object> arraylist;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            List<Object> objectList) {
        mContext = context;

        this.objectList = objectList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Object>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(objectList);

    }



    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        ImageView flag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objectList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objectList.get(position);
    }

public String getCountry(int position){return objectList.get(position).getCountry();}
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            //holder.rank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rank);
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

            // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
            holder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        // Set the results into TextViews
        //holder.rank.setText(objectList.get(position).getRank());
        holder.name.setText(objectList.get(position).getCountry());
        ;
        // Set the results into ImageView
        holder.flag.setImageResource(objectList.get(position)
                .getFlag());

        // Listen for ListView Item Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class

                // Pass all data rank

                // Start SingleItemView Class

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, animalbite.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent i2 = new Intent(mContext, asthmaattack.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(i2);break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent i3 = new Intent(mContext, choking.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(i3);break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent i4 = new Intent(mContext, cpr.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(i4);break;
                    case 4:
                        Intent i5 = new Intent(mContext, lackeye.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(i5);break;
                    case 5:
                        Intent i6 = new Intent(mContext, drowning.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(i6);break;
                    case 6:
                        Intent i7 = new Intent(mContext, Fracture.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(i7);break;
                    case 7:
                        Intent i8 = new Intent(mContext, heartattack.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(i8);break;
                    case 8:
                        Intent i9 = new Intent(mContext, insectbite.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(i9);break;
                    case 9:
                        Intent i10 = new Intent(mContext, poisoning.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(i10);break;
                    case 10:
                        Intent i11 = new Intent(mContext, spinalinjury.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(i11);break;

                }}});

        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        objectList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            objectList.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (Object wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getCountry().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    objectList.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Object.java

```
    public class Object {
    private String rank;
    private String country;
    private int flag;

    public Object(String rank, String country,
                  int flag) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.country = country;

        this.flag = flag;
    }



    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }



    public int getFlag() {
        return this.flag;
    }
}
```

How can I open different activities while clicking on listview items after I filter them.

This is the sample code I used. Although it doesn't provide the functionality to open original activities through intent ,just some forged up activity,so I'm trying to change that.
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: you mean position in `(int) adapter.getItemId(position)` is same for all filtering?

Comment: You really messed up with the code. If you have issues with the listview item click than post only the relevant code for the item click. Use itemclicklistener for listview and only there implement the relevant code for clicking, you've also set a clicklistener on the view itself inside the getview method which is totally unclear.

Comment: yes ,it always redirects to first activity despite the cases. @Mahdi.Pishguy

Comment: I have provided the ListViewAdapter code for reference to the filter function,just to make things clear. Also, my issue is with the  `public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    final int position, long id)` in which the intent is not working correctly. @Juvi

Answer (score 0):

I think your adapter has problem, this below sample code of my application is  extended from `Filterable` and work fine

```
public class AdapterContacts extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private List<ContactLists> categoryArrayList;
    private final ArrayList<ContactLists> originalList = new ArrayList<ContactLists>();
    private NameFilter filter;

    public AdapterContacts(ArrayList<ContactLists> array) {
        categoryArrayList = array;
    }

    public AdapterContacts(Context context, List<ContactLists> array) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        categoryArrayList = array;
        originalList.addAll(array);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categoryArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactLists getItem(int position) {
        return categoryArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_contacts_list_item, null);
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ContactLists item = getItem(position);
        mViewHolder.fillItems(this, item, position);

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class UI extends HelperUI {
        public TextView tv_person_nickname_mobile_number;
        public TextView btn_invite_message;
        public ImageView img_contact_image;
        public ImageView imgv_user_rank;
        public TextView tv_contact_name;
        public LinearLayout ll_root;

        public UI(View view) {
            parseUi(view);
        }
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private UI UI;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            UI = new UI(view);
        }

        public void fillItems(final AdapterContacts adapter, final ContactLists item, final int position) {
            UI.tv_contact_name.setText(item.getContact_name());

            if (item.getStatus() == 1) {
                UI.btn_invite_message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                UI.imgv_user_rank.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (item.getRank() != null || !TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getRank())) {
                    //Picasso.with(G.context).load(item.getRank()).into(UI.imgv_user_rank);
                }

                UI.tv_person_nickname_mobile_number.setText(item.getNick_name());
                //UI.ll_root.setBackgroundDrawable(G.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_button_actions));
                if (item.getContact_image() == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getContact_image())) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = UC.getContactPhoto(item.getMobile_number(), G.context.getContentResolver());
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        UI.img_contact_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } else {
                        UI.img_contact_image.setImageDrawable(G.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_avatar));
                    }
                } else {
                    // show user avatar from web
                    //Picasso.with(G.context).load(item.getContact_image()).into(UI.img_contact_image);
                    UI.img_contact_image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(G.DIR_IMAGE + "/" + item.getContact_image()));
                }
            } else {
                // UI.ll_root.setBackgroundDrawable(G.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_invite_actions));
                UI.btn_invite_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                UI.imgv_user_rank.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                UI.btn_invite_message.setText(UC.getString(R.string.invite_person));
                UI.btn_invite_message.setBackgroundDrawable(G.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_invite_button_default));
                UI.tv_person_nickname_mobile_number.setText(item.getMobile_number());
                Bitmap bitmap = UC.getContactPhoto(item.getMobile_number(), G.context.getContentResolver());
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    UI.img_contact_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    UI.img_contact_image.setImageDrawable(G.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_avatar));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new NameFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    public class NameFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            String searchText = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            ArrayList<ContactLists> newList = filterListBasedOnSearchText(searchText);
            results.values = newList;
            results.count = newList.size();

            return results;
        }

        private ArrayList<ContactLists> filterListBasedOnSearchText(String constraint) {
            ArrayList<ContactLists> newList = new ArrayList<ContactLists>();

            int l = originalList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                ContactLists nameList = originalList.get(i);

                if (nameList.getContact_name().toString().contains(constraint)) {
                    newList.add(nameList);
                }
            }

            return newList;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            categoryArrayList = (ArrayList<ContactLists>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```